# How to keep the XML tag value when renaming the tag using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to know how to keep the XML tag value when re-naming the tag using XSLT. Below is my xml, xslt, and the desired result. I am not sure how to do this so I have attempted this using variable and also choose when and otherwise tags in XLST.

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x>
    <y>
        <z value="john" designation="manager">
            <z value="mike" designation="associate"></z>
            <z value="dave" designation="associate"></z>
        </z>
    </y>
</x>
```

The XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="var"> 
name="manager value=\"sam\""
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="x">
    <employees>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </employees>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="y">
    <employee>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </employee>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="z">
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="sam">
    <xsl:element name="{$var}">
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:element name="{@designation}">
       <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
     </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees>
    <employee>
        <manager value="john">
            <associate>mike</associate>
            <associate>dave</associate>
        </manager>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Comment: The example is ambiguous - please explain the required logic in words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="x">
        <employees>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </employees>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="y">
        <employee>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </employee>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[contains(@designation, 'manager')]">
        <manager>
            <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </manager>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[contains(@designation, 'associate')]">
        <associate>
            <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        </associate>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```